# MakerDao defaulting to high gas limit

Tags: metamask, gas, fees, makerdao

I'm trying to pay back about 50 DAI and unlock 0.78 ETH but it keeps defaulting to 4 million gas limit (I usually see that amount as 300,000)...for a total of 0.82 ETH....I get the gas fees are high now but it says 0.82 for gas fee and 0.82 for amount + gas fee. So I have no idea whether this transaction will cost me $1300 to payback my 50 dai or is it including the ETH that I am unlocking?

[image: is this including my locked eth]

So this is a 2 part question

1. What is the difference between Gas Fee and Amount + Gas Fee
2. Why is it defaulting to such a high gas limit (I tried reducing it and it failed and ran out of gas). Seems ludicrous that I would pay $1300 for a transaction to pay back 50 Dai

Thanks

Comment: 1. Amount is the amount of ETH that you're sending to the contract (here 0), and Gas fee is Gwei * GasLimit (205*4000000) = 820000000 Gwei = 0.82 ETH
2. No idea, but depending on the smart contract, gas costs can be high, can you send the address of the contract?

Comment: Ok so I'm not misunderstanding this...if I was sending 0.1 eth and the cost to send was 0.02 then Gas would be 0.02 and Amount + Gas would be 0.12 -- As for sending the contract address I cannot as it links to financial info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to metamask and receive(d) failed transactions as well, and also default not 21000 gas limit but like 200-300k which makes the fee around 50-80$.
What I found, and like to share, is:
Go to settings, general, advance, and there you can click on 'reset' and all previous transactions and history is gone (NOT your money). This seems to be helping for some.
Sadly I have not found a way to send transaction atm - I'll share if I find a solution.
My take-away: metamask sucks, Eth fees too high, time for change to BSC or Eth sidechains